Odoo error that doesn't break any of my modules that states: empty or missing header
Has anybody seen this error before:
ERROR Production odoo.addons.bus.websocket: 400 Bad Request: Empty or missing header(s): upgrade
I'm working with Odoo 16, creating custom modules. It doesn't disrupt the code from running and I don't know where it's coming from. I can see when I check my logs but that's the only description that I got.

That's probably something with the nginx configuration, if you use nginx. There is a example config in the docs. Did you forget to set up everything for the websocket?

I set up what I thought was the right way. That's what it looks like but I'm not sure if that's all that needed:
    location /websocket {
        proxy_read_timeout 600s;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8069;
 proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;

